# REGEX for a specific Date in Title

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a lot of posts in a table that have a date title string, e.g. "1.1.1990" or "31.12.2000".

I am looking for a regex way to make a mysql query that gives me

a) posts between certain years (e.g. 1960 - 1990)

b) posts between a exact date (e.g. 1.1.1960 - 31.12.1990)

I tried it like this somehow:

```
SELECT ID FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%.1960'
```

(which gives me all posts that have "1960" in the post_title so I could do a loop for all other years and add the results together)

BUT: I thought it must be easier possible somehow with a regular expression,
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title REGEXP '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$'
```

... where the last digit however can be date range (1960 - 1990) for example.

Is it possible?

Comment: why not store the dates in an actual date format? and as a builtin date type?

Comment: I actually asked already, but the database structure is already made..

Comment: What is the datatype. Why not explore the option of between operator. `cast(SUBSTRING(post_title, -4) as int) between YEAR_01 and YEAR_02` or `STR_TO_DATE(post_title, '%d.%m.%Y') between DATE_01 and DATE_02`

Answer (score 2):

you should use string_to_date() this way you are parsing your dates to an actual date in mysql which allows you to use all of the built in functions like YEAR and BETWEEN

```
SELECT ID 
FROM posts
WHERE YEAR(string_to_date(post_title, '%m.%d.%Y')) > 1959 AND YEAR(string_to_date(post_title, '%m.%d.%Y')) < 1991
```

and for a range

```
SELECT ID 
FROM posts
WHERE string_to_date(post_title, '%m.%d.%Y') BETWEEN '1960-01-01' AND '1990-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Dates between years 1962 and 1995

   `'\d\d?\.\d\d?\.19(6[2-9]|[7-8][0-9]|9[0-5])'`
2. Dates between exact dates 1.2.1962 and 10.8.1995

   `'(([1-9]|[1-2][0-9])\.([1-9]|1[1-2])1962|\d\d?\.\d\d?\.19(6[3-9]|[7-8][0-9]|9[0-4])|([1-9]|10)\.[1-8]\.1995'`

And I hope you see that regex is not a good solution for the problem. You definitely will not find a simple solution 'cause working with dates is non trivial, as we see from all the programming languages.

Consider that all the needed regex stuff is already encapsulated in STR_TO_DATE function (which, I believe, was tested better than any solution you can find among the answers here) and there's no need to puzzle yourself. So you need to cut dates from title string, convert them into date type and compare with boundary dates.

Answer (score -1):

I think substring function would be easy to extract date and then compare it using date comparison with actual date.

You can add separate column in your table by extracting date from title. or compare it runtime in where condition.

1) If you add date_title then

UPDATE post
  set date_title=STR_TO_DATE(
           CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '.', -1),
           '-',
           SUBSTRING(post_title,locate('.',post_title)+1,2),
           '-',
           SUBSTRING(post_title,1,locate('.',post_title)-1)),
          '%Y-%m-%d')  ;

2) OR use in where condition.

select * from post where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '.', -1),'-',SUBSTRING(post_title,locate('.',post_title)+1,2),'-',SUBSTRING(post_title,1,locate('.',post_title)-1)),'%Y-%m-%d')='2015-10-01'